# How can I make custom skins for agar.io?

Tags: agar.io

How can I make agar.io skins? I don't remember how to make skins for agar.io. I want to make agar.io skins on the PC version with my friend.

Answer (score -2):

You really can't do this unless you have a mod, [like this one.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/agariomods-evergreen-scri/nhjgdbihpkphlammdaeicdemggagfbdo?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

If you still want a skin use this:

## Chrome, IE and Firefox

[Download](https://agariomods.com/index.html)

[Links](http://connect.agariomods.com/index.php)

## Chrome

## Firefox